# No callback with mongoose Model.create method

Tags: node.js, mongodb, migration, mongoose

I'm following this documentation:
http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.create

I'm trying to do the same here, by initializing my database. (Using `mongo-migrate`)

```
Category.create([
    {
        code: '0',
        name: CATEGORIES.LANGUAGE_STATUS
    },
    {
        code: '1',
        name: CATEGORIES.ACCESS_NAME
    },
    {
        code: '2',
        name: CATEGORIES.TRANSLATION_STATUS
    },
    {
        code: '3',
        name: CATEGORIES.ROLE_NAME
    }],
    function(error, data, data1){
        console.log(error)
        console.log(data)
        console.log(data1)
    }
);
```

When I run the script from mongo-migrate, I got nothing on the console. If I run it in my IDE via a run configuration I got a `null`, meaning there is no error but nothing else. In both case the data are correctly added in the database.

I don't understand why I don't get the `data` or `data1` because the doc says that I should get an object for each object I put in the array. I tried the three examples and still the same. (Promise, array and infinite parameters)

And I don't know why I don't have any logs.

I just tried again but from my program this time and I get correctly the callbacks.
Should I assume that there is a problem with the mongo-migrate module that don't trigger callbacks? I tried to run the script in debug mode (IDE) and I couldn't reach the callback when I could reach the call to the functions.

What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

I found why... So tricky...

The problem was that I didn't write anything on the standard output.
If I do a simple `console.log('whatever')` then all `console.log` in callbacks display correctly the message I expected...

Lost hours for nothing -_-.